# Fontawesome 5 icons broken when hosting locally

Tags: font-awesome-5

I have found an interesting issue and haven't been able to find a solution. Fontawesome 5 icons are displaying as broken icons when I host the files locally but will work when using the CDN. I am developing using Asp.Core using Libman for package management and the locally files are the same as the CDN files

[image: Broken Icons]

Style Tags tried:

```
<!--Doesn't Work-->
<link href="~/lib/font-awesome-5/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!--Works-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Libman Json: (Note that the files are the CDN files)

```
 {
  "provider": "filesystem",
  "library": "https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css",
  "destination": "wwwroot/lib/font-awesome-5/",
  "files": [
    "css/all.css",
    "js/all.js",
    "webfonts/fa-brands-400.eot",
    "webfonts/fa-brands-400.svg",
    "webfonts/fa-brands-400.ttf",
    "webfonts/fa-brands-400.woff",
    "webfonts/fa-brands-400.woff2",
    "webfonts/fa-regular-400.eot",
    "webfonts/fa-regular-400.svg",
    "webfonts/fa-regular-400.ttf",
    "webfonts/fa-regular-400.woff",
    "webfonts/fa-regular-400.woff2",
    "webfonts/fa-solid-900.eot",
    "webfonts/fa-solid-900.svg",
    "webfonts/fa-solid-900.ttf",
    "webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff",
    "webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff2"
  ]
}
```

[image: Local files are loaded]

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Just happens that writing the question out helped me think of a solution. There must be something different in the files that Font Awesome distributes at their CDN and the files that are provided for direct download, NPM, and Yarn. Using the directly downloaded files everything works but still wanting to use LibMan to handle third party files I used the unpkg.com CDN url provided at https://yarnpkg.com/en/package/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free. I hope this helps anyone else that might run into this issue.